# Storing Odd and Even numbers in an Array

Tags: c, arrays

We were tasked to make a program that accepts ONLY ten inputs from the user and then sort it into an Even or Odd Array.

1. Accepts 10 inputs.
2. Segregates to an Even or Odd Array.
3. Print how many are in the Even/Odd Array.
4. Print the numbers in each Array.

This is the program I made:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int even[10];
int odd[10];
int number;
int numOdd = 0;
int numEven = 0;
int sizeOdd = 0;
int sizeEven = 0;
int count;

printf("Input numbers:\n");
for(count = 0; count < 10; count++){
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number %2 == 0){
        while (numEven < 10){
            even[numEven++] = number;
            sizeEven++;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (numOdd < 10){
            odd[numOdd++] = number;
            sizeOdd++;
        }
    }
}

printf("\n\nEven numbers(%d): ", sizeEven);
for(number = 0; number < numEven; number++){
    printf("%d, ", even[number]);
}

printf("\n\nOdd numbers(%d): ", sizeOdd);
for(number = 0; number < numOdd; number++){
    printf("%d, ", odd[number]);
}

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

But my program just outputs the first numbers in the array and repeats it. Like, if I input 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, I get:

Even numbers (10): 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
Odd numbers (10): 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

Am I wrong with everything/my logic in the program? Am I on the right track and I just have to tweak it a bit? Hope for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:
 Why do you add that while loop inside the if and else condition:

```
if (number %2 == 0){
   even[numEven++] = number;
```

Also `even[numEven++]` itself increses the value of numEven variable no need to increment again in the next line.

Comment: YES! It did output the right numbers. Thank you very much! Now if only I can get it to print how many Odd and Even numbers there are...

Comment: `numEven` and `sizeEven` are two different variables - though they are basically duplicating each other.

Comment: @Steve314 Yes, I did not notice that ! Sorry for that thing !

Answer (score 0):

You've used `while` twice, where you should have used `if`. As a result, your `even` array will be filled with the first even number entered, and your `odd` array will be filled with the first odd number.

Change each `while` to an `if` and you may be OK, though I haven't checked for other errors. For example...

```
if (number %2 == 0){
    if (numEven < 10){
        even[numEven++] = number;
        sizeEven++;
    }
}
```

The `while` keyword defines a complete loop of it's own - it's not a limit on some other kind of repetition such as (in this case) your addition of elements to each array.

BTW - you don't really need the `if` checks either. You only input 10 items, so at most you can add 10 items to the `even` array, or 10 items to the `odd` array. As the arrays are both large enough to take 10 items, you don't need bounds checks in this code.

Answer (score 0):

The while keyword defines a complete loop of it's own - it's not a limit on some other kind of repetition such as (in this case) your addition of elements to each array.

BTW - you don't really need the if checks either. You only input 10 items, so at most you can add